# How to import many .txt files to R fast

Tags: r, performance, file-import

I am looking for speed improvement for a function which imports several ".txt" files to one data frame (adding file name). The number of ".txt" files is > 10 000 and all those files have the same structure and are located in one directory with several sub directories. Size of all 10 000 files is around 800 MB in total. It takes couple of hours to load all 10 000 file to a df.
My PC: Toshiba P50t with 8GB RAM and 1TB HDD

Please see the code I am using.
I am happy to hear suggestions how to improve loading speed (I would prefer not to use intermediary tool like load data to MS SQL and import it to R) I have tried to use fread instead of read_csv without significant speed difference.

```
files_to_df_v01 <- function( directory , Output_file_name , What_stocks) {

  List <-   data.frame(dir(directory, pattern="*.txt", recursive = T))
  names(List)[1] <- "Path_file"
  List <-  arrange(List,List$Path_file)
  List_wse_stocks <- (filter ( List , str_count(List$Path_file , pattern = What_stocks ) > 0 ))

  library(readr)

  rownumber = 1
  setwd(directory)

  ############## LOOP ################ 

  for (i in List_wse_stocks$Path_file) {    
    if (file.info(i)$size != 0) {           
      dat <- read_csv(i,col_types = cols(Ticker = col_character(), Date = col_date(format = "%Y-%m-%d"), Open = col_double(), High = col_double(), Low = col_double(), Close = col_double(), Volume = col_integer(), OpenInt = col_integer() ))
      L_ = (str_locate_all(i,"/")) 
      sapply(L_,max) 
      File_name <- substr(i,sapply(L_,max)+1, nchar(i)) 
      dat$Ticker <- substr(File_name,1,nchar(File_name)-4) 
      datt = dat %>% select(Ticker, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, OpenInt)
      if (rownumber == 1) { rownumber = rownumber + 1
      GPW_wse_stocks <- datt }
      else{GPW_wse_stocks <- rbind(GPW_wse_stocks, datt)}
    }   
  }   
  # )                   ##############  END of LOOP

  save(GPW_wse_stocks,file=Output_file_name)

  return(data.frame(GPW_wse_stocks)) 

}
```

Comment: Possibly calling rbind 10 000 times is slow. Take a look at purrr::map_dfr.

Comment: `data.table::fread()` for fastest read-in and def either use `purrr` mapping functions or `lapply` and `data.table::rbindlist()`. But, it's likely this q will get closed due to there being dozens of them on SO.

Comment: Have you profiled your code?

Comment: What's your operating system? Do the files each have a header? Can you supply the `head()` of one of them?

Comment: Operating system: Windows 10 Home

Comment: Ticker       Date   Open   High    Low  Close Volume OpenInt
1 1499.n 2012-09-28 100.02 100.02 100.02 100.02      0       0
2 1499.n 2012-10-01 100.05 100.05 100.05 100.05      0       0
3 1499.n 2012-10-02 100.05 100.05 100.05 100.05      0       0

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` I managed to get around 4 times faster solution:

```
# Creating test data :

dir.create("Test")
dd <- "Test/csvReadingTest2"
dir.create(dd)
dir.create(file.path(dd, "v1"))
dir.create(file.path(dd, "v2"))

n <- 3000
f <- function(x) sample(x, n, replace = T)
require(data.table)
set.seed(123)
d1 <- data.table(Ticker = f(LETTERS),
                 Date = f(seq.Date(as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = "month",
                                   length.out = n/100)),
                 Open = f(c(1.2, 1.3)), High = f(c(1.2, 1.3)),
                 Low = f(c(1.2, 1.3)), Close = f(c(1.2, 1.3)),
                 Volume = f(1:10), OpenInt = f(1:10))
d1
#       Ticker       Date Open High Low Close Volume OpenInt
#    1:      H 2203-04-01  1.2  1.3 1.2   1.2      6       4
#    2:      N 2121-05-01  1.2  1.3 1.2   1.2      9       6
#    3:      E 2060-04-01  1.3  1.2 1.2   1.3      1       3
#    4:      V 2132-04-01  1.3  1.3 1.3   1.2      7       8
#    5:      F 2253-04-01  1.2  1.3 1.3   1.2      3      10
#  ---                                                     
# 2996:      J 2027-05-01  1.3  1.3 1.2   1.2      7       6
# 2997:      K 2177-05-01  1.2  1.3 1.2   1.2      5       4
# 2998:      S 2200-03-01  1.2  1.2 1.2   1.2      6       2
# 2999:      V 2110-05-01  1.3  1.3 1.3   1.2      4       3
# 3000:      Q 2043-05-01  1.2  1.3 1.2   1.2      3       5

invisible(lapply(1:100, function(x) fwrite(d1, paste0(dd, "/v1/d", x, ".txt"))))
invisible(lapply(1:100, function(x) fwrite(d1, paste0(dd, "/v2/d", x, ".txt"))))
```

A little bit modified your function:

```
################################################################################

yourFunction_modified <- function(directory, Output_file_name, What_stocks) {

  # require(plyr)
  require(dplyr)
  require(stringr)
  library(readr)

  # List <-   data.frame(dir(directory, pattern = "*.txt", recursive = T))
  # names(List)[1] <- "Path_file"
  # List <-  arrange(List, List$Path_file)
  # List_wse_stocks <- (filter(List , str_count(List$Path_file ,
  #                                               pattern = What_stocks ) > 0 ))

  l <- list.files(directory, recursive = T, full.names = T, pattern = "*.txt")
  l <- l[grepl(What_stocks, l)]

  rownumber = 1

  for (i in l) {    
    if (file.info(i)$size != 0) {           
      dat <- read_csv(i,
                      col_types = cols(Ticker = col_character(),
                                       Date = col_date(format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                                       Open = col_double(), High = col_double(),
                                       Low = col_double(), Close = col_double(),
                                       Volume = col_integer(),
                                       OpenInt = col_integer()))
      L_ = (str_locate_all(i,"/")) 
      File_name <- substr(i,sapply(L_,max) + 1, nchar(i)) 
      dat$Ticker <- substr(File_name,1,nchar(File_name) - 4) 
      datt = dat %>% select(Ticker, Date, Open, High, Low, Close,
                            Volume, OpenInt)
      if (rownumber == 1) {
        rownumber = rownumber + 1
        GPW_wse_stocks <- datt
      } else {
          GPW_wse_stocks <- rbind(GPW_wse_stocks, datt)
      }
    } 
  }   
  save(GPW_wse_stocks, file = Output_file_name)
  return(data.frame(GPW_wse_stocks)) 
}


system.time(
  x <- yourFunction_modified(dd, file.path(dirname(dd), "csvReadingTest2.Rdat"),
                       "/d[0-9]")
)

 # 25 - 18 sek
```

My function:

```
myFun <- function(directory, Output_file_name, What_stocks) {
  require(data.table)
  require(Hmisc)

  l <- list.files(directory, recursive = T, full.names = T, pattern = "*.txt")
  l <- l[grepl(What_stocks, l)]
  l <- l[file.info(l)$size != 0]

  dtList <- lapply(l, function(i) { 
      dat <- fread(i)
      File_name <- basename(i)
      dat$Ticker <- substr(File_name, 1, nchar(File_name) - 4) 
      necessary <- Cs(Ticker, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, OpenInt)
      # Delete unnecesary columns:
      for (ii in setdiff(colnames(dat), necessary)) {
        set(dat, j = ii, value = NULL)
      }
      dat
  })
  dtList[1:2]
  dt <- rbindlist(dtList, use.names = T, fill = T, idcol = F)
  require(fasttime)
  dt[, Date := as.Date(fastPOSIXct(Date))]
  save(dt, file = Output_file_name)
  return(dt[]) 
}

system.time(
  x2 <- myFun(dd, file.path(dirname(dd), "csvReadingTest2v2.Rdat"),
                       "/d[0-9]")
)

# 6 - 4 sek

all.equal(as.data.table(x), x2)
# [1] TRUE1
```

Comment: I have tried this solutions and it speed up the process of importing my files dramatically  (to below 6 minutes [before it was > 4 hours]) many thanks!
Which part in your opinion was most significant to increase speed?

Comment: @Jarek Getting rid of `rbind` and `select` functions, they were the slowest

Answer (score 2):

`rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))` is pretty quick, though if you have a high number of small files and you don't care about preserving the filename, you may be best using the operating system directly.

Set up data because OP didn't: 10,000 files of 100 rows.

```
setwd(tempdir())
dir.create("48492154")
setwd("48492154")


dates <- as.character(seq.Date(as.Date("2012-01-01"),
                               as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                               length.out = 500))

library(data.table)
for (i in 1:1e4) {
  DT <- data.table(Ticker = 1:100,
                   Date = sample(dates, size = 100),
                   Open = round(runif(100) + 100, 1),
                   Close = round(runif(100) + 100, 1),
                   Volume = sample(1:100),
                   OpenInt = 1:100)
  cat(i, "of 10,000\r") 
  flush.console()
  fwrite(DT, paste0(i, ".csv"), showProgress = FALSE)
}
```

Simple method (also handles repeated headers and gets the colClasses nearer to the truth.)

```
system.time({
  res <- rbindlist(lapply(dir(pattern = "\\.csv"), fread))
})
#>   user  system elapsed 
#>   5.46    3.17    8.62
```

Using Windows's system `copy`:

```
system.time({
  # Windows only
  shell("copy /b *.csv out.txt > dump.log")
  new_res <- fread("out.txt")

  # Delete the headers mixed in (whereas rbindlist() above
  # handles this automatically -- and better)
  for (j in names(new_res)) {
    new_res <- new_res[.subset2(new_res, j) != j]
  }
})

#>   user  system elapsed 
#>   0.76    0.13    3.31
```

Comment: Depending on the hardware using `parallel::mclapply` in place of `lapply` can speed things up considerably.

Comment: Very true, though (1) OP says he's on Windows, which doesn't support `mclapply` and (2) `copy /b` is parallelized afaict.